# Export data to preload into a Firebase instance in a mobile app

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The use case is a dual platform mobile app for an event. There is a schedule with photos, links, bios of the speakers and talk descriptions. If all of the attendees happen to download and open the app at the same time and in the same place, they might not get the best experience -> the WiFi might slow the calls into the data server, calls into the FireBase server side will spike.

Is it possible to export a database from the server side and preload the event schedule data into the mobile app download? Upon launch the app can sync any last minute updates, as needed, with a connection and a short sync to Firebase.

If this type of architecture is not available, is there an alternative that the Firebase team would recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way within the Firebase Database API to preload data into the disk cache.

Two things I can think of (neither of them very nice):

1. Have the client read the JSON file from your app's resources and *write* it to the location. The end result of this will be that the data on the server stays unmodified. But it does result in each client *writing* the same data to the server, so the inverse of your original problem (and likely worse performing).
2. Have a wrapper around the Firebase API calls that loads from the JSON file and then have them later attach listeners after a random delay (to reduce the rush on the app).

As said, neither of them is very good. For both of them, you can download the JSON from the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/).

In my experience the usage of conference apps is a lot lower than most developers/organizers imagine. It's also typically quite well spread out over the duration of the conference. So reducing the amount of data you load might be enough to make things work.

Comment: This is true for the most part, but some things like images and other richer media can do some damage on conference room wifiz <3

Comment: When dealing with realtime data synchronization *always* look for ways to minimize the data that needs to be synchronized. So don't store such blob-like objects in the database, but instead store them as files. You can where possible ship the files with your app as resources, and store potential updates on Cloud Storage. Then link to the files from within the database. and fingerprint the URLs or use a timestamp to indicate the last update (to help you determine whether your should load it from local resources or Cloud Storage).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Image files are a cause for concern. Paths on the website for a download can be the source for photos. 
1. build the client structures locally from exported JSON 
2. use timestamps to qualify all client side Firebase queries. 
The seed data of the schedule is local JSON and won't be in Firebase on the client. The client queries for data newer than the seed data, every query is qualified that way. Results from the server overwrite the locally loaded data when there is any duplication.
Does that sound right? @FrankvanPuffelen Does it sound difficult?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds feasible but rather convoluted. I really wonder how big your schedule JSON is going to be, and if this pre-loading is actually needed. If you keep the JSON small and do some napkin calculations, this might all be unnecessary.

Comment: If you want, just ignore the issues caused by limited bandwidth of the WiFi at a conference venue. It's not the the size of the data. It's the out of box experience (OOBE) For example, attendees at the DevFest DC workshops were hampered when the WiFi could not meet the demand. I don't want that experience in my apps. It may be easy for you and others to dismiss -> I make apps that fly.

Comment: Unfortunately the Firebase Database doesn't have an API that allows you to pre-seed the cache. So a custom client-side data access layer may be the way to go indeed.

Answer (score 0):

On android you can ship a sql database in the assets directory with the app and then reconcile it with the updates when the users open the app. The Firebase database is a json file. You could also ship that in the assets directory and then reconcile on first load.

Comment: Yes, it's the "reconcile" part that is important. Do you have any examples?